# Не работает ни один триггер в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, триггер

Я добавляю триггеры в свою БД, далее пытаюсь выполнить запрос, запрос выполняется, а триггер нет. Привожу в пример один из созданных триггеров и запрос после которого он должен по идее срабатывать. Таблицы в MyISAM

```
update userStatus set idStatus = 333 where idStatus = 2;

Create trigger update_user_status_for_client after update on userStatus
For each row
Update Clients set status = NEW.idStatus where status = OLD. idStatus;
```

Результат show create table для таблиц:

```
userStatus


 'CREATE TABLE `userStatus` (
`idStatus` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`title` varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`idStatus`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'

clients


 'CREATE TABLE `clients` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Surname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Middlename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'1\',
`gender` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'1\',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=28571 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Comment: Триггер 100% работает. Сразу после запроса что выдает `show warnings;`? Ну и `show create table` для обоих таблиц в студию

Comment: Добавил show create table в пост вопроса. show warnings выдает пустую таблицу.

Comment: Было подозрение что `status` `TINYINT` - в этом случае была бы ошибка в триггере. Но нет. `mysql> update userStatus set idStatus = 333 where idStatus = 3;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.Clients' doesn't exist`. Таблицы Clients нет. Таблица не в том регистре. Или у вас винда?

Comment: Все, проблема решена, спасибо

Comment: Винда. Проблема была в моей небольшой невнимательности

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, ответ на свой вопрос и пометьте его как решение. Тут люди обмениваются данными, другой зайдет, и найдет ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: При выполнении кода я забыл что при дописывании оператора explain запрос не выполняется, а только оценивается и соответственно ломал голову что же не так.

Answer (score 0):

Возможные причины

## Таблица не существует

В DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `clients`
```

В триггере:

```
Update Clients
```

Таблицы различаются регистром символов. Для MySQL в среде Windows это не имеет значения. Для остальных систем - важно.

## Ошибку не видно

Сразу после `UPDATE`-запроса смотрим `show warnings;`. Будут выведены ошибки и предупреждения.

```
+-------+------+------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                            |
+-------+------+------------------------------------+
| Error | 1146 | Table 'test.Clients' doesn't exist |
+-------+------+------------------------------------+
```

## Изучение DDL

Смотрим `show create table`.

Если размерность `status` меньше, чем `idStatus`, запрос сработает, но триггер - нет. Это не фатальная ошибка. Следует использовать `show warnings;` для диагностики такой проблемы.

## Невнимательность

При дописывании оператора explain `UPDATE`-запрос не выполняется.

Для диагностики смотрим количество затронутых строк. Если `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)`, запрос не внес изменения.